# How to create this matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to create the following picture in LaTeX. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can also start searching for on this site

Comment: which site exactly? How can i search something like this in this site?!

Comment: @tanha, on the top, there is a search field. See the black bar on the top.

Comment: I know that. I mean how can i search specifically the one i want to create?!!

Comment: How to create Toeplitz matrix in Latex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will serve as a starting point for the OP to learn. Here the proposal uses array where you specifies how many columns you need, for example, by using `cccc` for 4 columns centered, and then separate each column by & and ends the line by \.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paper size={15cm,8cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{lccccccccccccc}
m:              &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 &0  & 0 & 0 &  &      \\
d(1)=0          &-1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &   &   &  &   &   &      & &    \\
d(2)=0          &   &   &-1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &  &   &   &   &  &      \\
d(3)=0          &   &   &   &-1 & 2 & 1 &   &  &   &   &      & &    \\
$\ldots\ldots$  &   &   &   &   &   &   & $\ldots$ & & &   &         \\
d(5)=1          &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &$\ldots$  &   &  & & &  \\
$\ldots\ldots$  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  & $\ldots$  &  &\\
d(11)=0 & & &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & -1   & 2 & 1  \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Edit: Recommended by barbara beeton, a flush right solution.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paper size={16cm,8cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
m:     &    &  & 0 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & 1 &0 &0 & \phantom{-}0 & 0 &&\\
d(1)=0 &-1  & \phantom{-}2& 1 &   &   &   &   &  &  &   &     && \\
d(2)=0 &    &  &-1   & 2 & 1  &   &   &   &   &  &  &   &        \\
d(3)=0 &    &  &     &-1 & 2  & 1 &   &   &   &  &  &   &        \\
$\ldots\ldots$ &     &   &    &   &   &   &  $\ldots$&  &     && \\
d(5)=1 &    &  &     &   &    &   &   &$\ldots$  &  &   &     && \\
$\ldots\ldots$ &     &   &    &   &   &   &   &   &  $\ldots$ & &\\
d(11)=0 &   &  &     &   &    &   &   &   &   &  & -1 & \phantom{-}2 & \phantom{-}1  \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: since some of the entries in the cells are negative, i'd be inclined to set the columns flush right rather than centered.

Comment: How to create Toeplitz matrix in Latex ?

Answer (score 10):

The hardest part is getting equal sized columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand{\two}[1]{\makebox[1.5em][r]{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\Ldots}{\dots\dots\hspace*{-1em}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l @{\quad} *{13}{>{\collectcell\two}c<{\endcollectcell}}}
\quad m & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
d(1)=0  & -1 & 2 &  1 \\
d(2)=0  &    &   & -1 & 2 &  1 \\
d(3)=0  &    &   &    &   & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
\dots   &    &   &    &   &    & \Ldots \\
d(5)=1  &    &   &    &   &    &   &  & \Ldots \\
\dots   &    &   &    &   &    &   &  &  &  & \Ldots \\
d(11)=0 &    &   &    &   &    &   &  &  &  &  & -1 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the dotted entries in the columns to the right appear in the original to "join" two columns rather than be centered on just one column.  maybe `\mathllap` from the rightmost affected column would produce that result.

Answer (score 5):

You could use two `array` environments, with the second one containing thirteen columns, and use `\phantom` instructions in the first row of the second `array` to get equal-width columns. If you want the "dots" placed on the baseline instead of centered vertically, use `\dots` instead of `\cdots`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{}l}
m:\\
d(1)=0\\
d(2)=0\\
d(3)=0\\
\cdots\\
d(5)=0\\
\cdots\\
d(11)=0
\end{array}
\quad
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{array}{*{13}{r}}
\phantom{-0} & \phantom{-0} 
& \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 
& \phantom{-}1 
& \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0
& \phantom{-0} & \phantom{-0} \\
-1 & 2 & 1\\
& & -1 & 2 & 1\\
& & & -1 & 2 & 1\\
& & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cdots}\\
& & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cdots}\\
& & & & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cdots}\\
& & & & & & & & & & -1 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```